# Word that means "sourceless"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means *without a source* but that is a little shorter and simple than *sourceless*. Coulnd't find any on [Thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/sourceless).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a suggestion:

aseity - the quality or state of being self-derived or self-originated

link - http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aseity

or try groundless or just source-less if it gets complicated.

Comment: +1. This is close to my suggestion as well.

Comment: How would you use this? *Your claim is aseitical!*?

Answer (score 1):

There are words like **groundless** and **unfounded** that basically mean that you don't have supporting facts but not exactly the same as sourceless.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of more context, I suggest "**self-manifested**".

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit prejudiced to the concept of *fons et origo* but a **hapax legomenon** is a [term of which only one instance of use is recorded](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pundigrion) and anything without an origin is **cryptogenic** or [a term that refers to something of obscure or unknown origin.](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/2787373)